# Jumping cursor in CKeditor

Tags: cursor, ckeditor

I am using CKeditor, version 4.4.1 and SCYAT for spelling check. When there is an error in the word, the cursor jumps to the beginning of this word. Is it possible to fix it somehow and make the cursor stay where is?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a bug reported for that and I think that it's already closed. You can search in the [SCAYT's bugs](https://github.com/WebSpellChecker/ckeditor-plugin-scayt/issues?page=1&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aclosed). If you can find it there, it means that the bug should be already fixed in latest SCAYT version.

However, CKEditor does not ship yet with the latest SCAYT, so you will need to build your own CKEditor using e.g. the [CKEditor presets](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-presets) repo and updating the SCAYT submodule there.

You can also wait for CKEditor 4.4.6, because very likely it will ship with the newest SCAYT.

Comment: It seems this error is not fixed. I tried their latest demo version. I have posted a [question](https://github.com/WebSpellChecker/ckeditor-plugin-scayt/issues/83) about this. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: As I wrote in my answer CKEditor does not ship yet with latest SCAYT, so no surprise that on the demo caret still jumps.